# Transform is not working for android but works for ios- react native

Tags: react-native

I am using react:16.0.0-beta.5 and react-native: 0.49.3, trying to rotate my graph at 180 degrees but when I pass transform in my style, all graphs disappear.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that? I have searched a lot but, didn't get any appropriate solution which works. It is working in iOS but doesn't work in Android.

Here is my code:

```
render(): Element {
    const transform = []
    if (this.props.h > 0) {
        transform.push({ rotateZ: "180deg"})
    }
    const band = {
        width: this.props.w,
        marginRight: 1,
        transform:transform,
    }

    const graphic = {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: this.props.w,
        height: Math.abs(this.props.h),
        borderRadius: this.props.w,
        backgroundColor: this.props.color,
    }
    return <View style={band}>
        <View style={graphic} />
    </View>
}
```

When I write transform in my  **const band** json, the graph disappears, and when I remove that it shows the graph but I have to apply transform to rotate the graph after some condition. If you see the screenshot, there is 5th graph is upside down in iOS, but lower in Android, because earlier I had implemented it on the base of the platform because transform makes the graph disappear for Android. I have used **perspective** also but didn't work.

[image]